# Packing and using external files in C# and Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am having trouble with external .json and .csv for a data parsing program. right now I have an unideal workaround where I read in the data from the user's appdata, but as you can imagine the files don't transfer whenever I upload to github and have to work on my laptop. How can I pack these files into my program, and further more how do I reference them once they are packed inside? I am using Visual Studio as my IDE at the moment.

I've been told it can be done with resource folders, but they seemingly only accept .resx files, with is a format I'm entirely unfamiliar with.

I have tried manually adding a folder to the solution, although I can't figure out what syntax is required to even reference it. I'm unsure if placing a folder in that location is even the correct thing to do.

Comment: Are you wanting these files to be permanently part of your application? Are they immutable e.g., won't change ever over the lifetime of a given version of your application?

Comment: What protocol are you using to upload/download files from github?  This is not a packing nor a Windows Form issue.  It is the protocol you are using to transfer the files.

Comment: @ChrisBD It's more than likely that these files will need to be updated at some point, although it would be incredibly infrequent. I might need to update this .csv file and .json every 3 to 4 months. For the intent of the program these would otherwise be read only.

Comment: @jdweng I am using the built in git tab in visual studio. my project, aside from these files transfer just fine between my desktop and laptop.

Comment: You want to transfer files automatically, not using the git tab in VS. Is this what you want to do : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: Have you tried saving it as an embedded resource and using the Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream method to read the data

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT I don't think so, but this sounds like what I need. How exactly do I embed a resource?